# Can the word もう be pronounced むう?

Tags: pronunciation

I heard the word もう (meaning "already, not anymore") pronounced as むう in this song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3R3uMTMHgPc at about 1:18, and yet it is transcribed as "mou". Is it a pronunciation mistake or a dialectal pronunciation? Did the person mistranscribe what is said, or did I simply mishear the word?
Thanks very much for your answers.

Comment: It sounds like もう to me, not at all like むう. Also, I don't think machines can make pronunciation mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The word actually sounds closer to むう to my ears, and it should definitely be pronounced as モー. I don't think dialects are relevant. In [this original video](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm5992615), I can see at least one comment pointing out that part sounds weird.

That said, I don't like to call it a pronunciation (or "input") mistake — although this song is known as one of the most natural, [well-"trained" Vocaloid songs by Luka Megurine](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/rip%3Drelease), her voice is synthesized after all, and her pronunciation is far from perfect. I don't recommend you learn something about pronunciation from Vocaloid songs.

Comment: Vocaloid is a good program to own and mess around with the basic sounds in, but I agree with naruto. Don't go learning how to say things from a machine; you're just asking for trouble that way.
It should also be noted that Vocaloids are notorious for containing numerous flaws within the encoding, recordings, pitch, pronunciation... The list goes on, as you might imagine.
If you're really looking to learn Japanese, do yourself a favor and stop using Vocaloid as a means to learn it and pick up what you can from human natives.

Comment: Good point. I imagine any English speaker would find ludicrous the idea of learning English pronunciation from text-to-speech software, so I wouldn't expect any different for any other language.